# simple scan doesn't launch 18.10

Tags: scanner, 18.10

Is this known that simple scan fails in 18.10?
It simply fails to come up.

I installed m1212nf mfp which isn't officially yet supported in18.10.
The fax/printer appears in the printer list.
The most important part is the scanner and for that I use simple scan.
The software installation of simple scan had no problems, but when I try to launch it, nothing happens.

Comment: You might find a better result if you use gscan2pdf downloadable from the Ubuntu Software Centre. This software seems much better at handling scanners in my experience.